# Error while connecting VPN using Cisco VPN Client

Tags: networking, cisco-vpn-client

Here is the log

```
Cisco Systems VPN Client Version 5.0.07.0410 Copyright (C) 1998-2010 Cisco Systems, Inc. All Rights Reserved. Client Type(s): Windows, WinNT Running on: 6.2.9200  Config file directory: C:\Program Files\Cisco Systems\VPN Client\


 1. 09:53:33.418  12/09/15  Sev=Warning/3   CVPND/0xE340000C The Client
    was unable to enable the Virtual Adapter because it could not open
    the device.

 2. 09:53:33.433  12/09/15  Sev=Warning/3   CVPND/0xE340000C The Client
    was unable to enable the Virtual Adapter because it could not open
    the device.

 3. 09:53:33.433  12/09/15  Sev=Warning/2   IKE/0xE300009B Failed to
    active IPSec SA: Unable to enable Virtual Adapter (NavigatorQM:936)

 4. 09:53:33.433  12/09/15  Sev=Warning/2   IKE/0xE30000A7 Unexpected SW
    error occurred while processing Quick Mode
    negotiator:(Navigator:2263)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which Windows ? Has it ever worked ?

Comment: Windows 8.1 Pro x86. This is the first time I'm using it.

Answer (score 2):

- Open Registry Editor i.e. `regedit`
- Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\vpnva`
- Double Click on DisplayName
- Remove characters like `@oem14.inf,%VPNVA64_Desc%` prefixed to DisplayName

[image]

- Try connecting again

Comment: Sorry for the late reply and thanks a bunch for your help, but it seems that I do not have and entry named vpnva in my registry.

Comment: @Vizkrig What are you using ? Cisco AnyConnect ? Look for this key then `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\CVirtA` and do the same as suggested above

Comment: I have the same problem. I have HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\CVirtA. But there is nothing strange with DisplayName, it's just "Cisco Systems VPN Adapter for 64-bit Windows". (Cisco VPN Client 5.0.07.0440 on 64-bit Windows 7)

Comment: I confirm the solution works on Windows 10 as well. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: 
After a bit of research and information from another community found the Cisco VPN is writing wrong values in the registry key for DisplayName string.

To fix the issue, we should change the value to below:
Open registry editor [From Windows Run type regedit] and move to the location: HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\CVirtA

```
For x86, change the value data from "@oem8.inf,%CVirtA_Desc%;Cisco Systems VPN Adapter" to "Cisco Systems VPN Adapter"
For x64, change the value data from "@oem8.inf,%CVirtA_Desc%;Cisco Systems VPN Adapter for 64-bit Windows" to "Cisco Systems VPN Adapter for 64-bit Windows"
```

Now, try to connect to VPN and it should work without any issues.